# Is there a way to disable VS intellisense warnings for std headers without wrapping every include with garbage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, intellisense

Visual Studio's intellisense produces the following warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data1' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   216 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   216 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data1' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   220 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   220 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data1' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   228 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::exception_ptr::_Data2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\exception   228 
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\map 144 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::error_category::_Addr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error    70  
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\unordered_map   200 
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash   413 
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xhash   577 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::ios_base::_Except' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase    460 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::ios_base::_Fmtfl' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase    460 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::ios_base::_Mystate' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase    460 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::ios_base::_Prec' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase    460 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::ios_base::_Wide' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase    460 
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::locale::_Ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 265 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 963 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '-' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '-' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 963 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 1074    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 1246    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 1321    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 1332    
Warning C26819  Unannotated fallthrough between switch labels (es.78).  MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 2014    
Warning C26819  Unannotated fallthrough between switch labels (es.78).  MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocale 2215    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char16_t> >::_Bxty::_Alias' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char16_t> >::_Bxty::_Buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char16_t> >::_Bxty::_Ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char32_t> >::_Bxty::_Alias' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char32_t> >::_Bxty::_Buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char32_t> >::_Bxty::_Ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >::_Bxty::_Alias' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >::_Bxty::_Buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> >::_Bxty::_Ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t> >::_Bxty::_Alias' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t> >::_Bxty::_Buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26495  Variable 'std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t> >::_Bxty::_Ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xstring 2252    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   MD  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xtree   907
```

I obviously don't want warnings from the std headers to be shown.
I came up with a very ugly work-around that consists in wrapping every single std inclusion in the whole project like so:

```
#include <CodeAnalysis/Warnings.h>
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: ALL_CODE_ANALYSIS_WARNINGS)
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

This looks like garbage and makes absolutely no sense.
Is there a simple and effective way to either tell intellisense to ignore the warnings for std headers, or at least make the above prettier?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn off all warnings under **Project Properties Settings**.

Right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**General**

change **Warning Level** to `Turn Off All Warnings(/W0)`

**Or** if you do not want to disable all warnings and just these displayed specific warnings, you could try these:

**Project Properties**-->**Configuration Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**Advanced**-->type these into **Disable Specific Warnings**:

```
26495;26439;26451;26819
```

I only found these and these methods will not let you suppress the code in each `cpp` file individually.

Comment: Yeah I was aware of that, unluckily it would be detrimental to turn off all warning types that happen in standard library headers, since the same warning could also happen inside my code, and I'd love that to be reported ^^
Well, I guess there is no other way than wrapping the includes with garbage then.

Comment: Sure.  That suppress all warnings is not a good choice. So you  could suppress the related specific warnings on your project. It will not interrupt the display of other types of warnings. Use this will help you. And let us know if this will help you.

Comment: Just to make my point absolutely clear: I don't want to turn off, let's say, 26495, because I *do* want it to report uninitialised members in *my* code.
Nevertheless, I do not care about that very same warning when it happens inside the standard library headers (because I didn't write them).
So there's no way I can solve my problem by disabling specific warnings.